# C++ tic tac toe game. Switches space instead of error message

Tags: c++

I'm new to coding and I am trying to make a tic tac toe game. I am not finished yet. But I am stuck, I want the program to print an error when a space is already taken. But now it just switches the original token with the new token. Like if there is an X in one space and player two goes in the same space, the O will replace the X. I have the declarations of the functions in a separate header file. Any criticism is greatly appreciated, good and bad.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "TicTacToe.h"


    bool TicTacToe::validPosition(int x, int y, int currentplayer){
        if(map[x][y] != ' '){
            return false;
        }
        map[y][x] = currentplayer;
        return true;

    }

    void TicTacToe::playgame() {
        int player1move;
        int player2move;
        int currentplayer;
        generateGrid();

        int x, y;

        while(gameover == false) {
            tictacToeMap();

                std::cout << "Go player one" << std::endl;
                std::cin >> player1move;


                if (player1move == 1) {
                    map[0][0] = 'x';
                } else if (player1move == 2) {
                    map[0][1] = 'x';
                } else if (player1move == 3) {
                    map[0][2] = 'x';
                } else if (player1move == 4) {
                    map[1][0] = 'x';
                } else if (player1move == 5) {
                    map[1][1] = 'x';
                } else if (player1move == 6) {
                    map[1][2] = 'x';
                } else if (player1move == 7) {
                    map[2][0] = 'x';
                } else if (player1move == 8) {
                    map[2][1] = 'x';
                } else if (player1move == 9) {
                    map[2][2] = 'x';
                }
                tictacToeMap();


                std::cout << "Go player two" << std::endl;
                std::cin >> player2move;
                if (player2move == 1) {
                    map[0][0] = 'o';
                } else if (player2move == 2) {
                    map[0][1] = 'o';
                } else if (player2move == 3) {
                    map[0][2] = 'o';
                } else if (player2move == 4) {
                    map[1][0] = 'o';
                } else if (player2move == 5) {
                    map[1][1] = 'o';
                } else if (player2move == 6) {
                    map[1][2] = 'o';
                } else if (player2move == 7) {
                    map[2][0] = 'o';
                } else if (player2move == 8) {
                    map[2][1] = 'o';
                } else if (player2move == 9) {
                    map[2][2] = 'o';
                }

            }

            if (validPosition(x, y, currentplayer) == true) {
                std::cout << "Cant go there" << std::endl;
            } else {
                if (currentplayer == player1move) {
                    currentplayer = player2move;
                } else {
                    currentplayer = player1move;
                }
        }


    }



    void TicTacToe::generateGrid() {
        int number = 1;

        for(int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++){
                map[x] [y] = std::to_string(number).c_str()[0];
                number += 1;
            }
        }
    }




    void TicTacToe::tictacToeMap(){



        std::cout << std:: endl;

        for(int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++){
                std::printf(" %c ",  map[x][y]) ;
            }
            std::cout << std:: endl;
        }

    }
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I don't think `validPosition` is a good name for a function that modifies the map. You should decide whether the function is just going to _look_ at the map, and return true/false based on what it sees, or _change_ the map (assuming it's okay to do so) in which case its name should reflect its more complex task. Also, decide whether you're going to access the map with `map[x][y]` or with `map[y][x]`. You shouldn't do both.

Comment: Whenever you see a section of code that looks like something identical that's been cut and pasted a few times with only some parameters changed, look for an opportunity to eliminate the redundancy.

Comment: You can simplify your program by using `switch`.  You could also simplify by using math:  `int row = (box_number - 1) / 3; int column = (box_number - 1) % 3;`

Comment: Also, try an initialization loop:  `char id = '1'; for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++row) { for (int column = 0; column < 3; ++ column) {map[row][column] = id; ++id;} }`

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be the very thing the validPosition function does - why not move it above the setting parts and show the error, rather than setting the value and then checking ?

In addition, the validPosition sets the value for you - as long as you give it the correct x,y

Comment: When I call the function above the settings the code builds and ends immediately.

Comment: my bet is that you didn't set x and y to anything

Comment: That is a good point `x` and `y` need to be correctly initialized depending on the move. This probably should be a function. something like `void getXYPositionFromMove(int move, int & x, int & y)` or just use the row  & column formulas from @ThomasMatthews